# Multivariable change of variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

In my PDE class, I have come across an integral in the form
$$
\int_{B(x,t)} \psi(y) dy.
$$

Then, the author makes the substitution $y = x + tw$ where $w = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta) \in B(0,1)$. Apparently, this implies that $dy = t^2 dw$ and the integral becomes

$$
\int_{B(0,1)} \psi(x + tw) t^2 dw.
$$

I understand why the integral is now over $B(0,1)$, but I don't understand why $dy = t^2 dw$. Can someone explain?

Comment: Do you know the change of variables formula? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables

Comment: @cmk I know how to use the formula for simpler examples, but I am confused with the determinant part for this example. I attempted write $y_1 = x_1 + t w_1$ and $y_2 = x_2 + t w_2$ and take the partial derivatives of $y_1$ and $y_2$ with respect to...something? But I am not sure of how to work the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function $\varphi(w)=x+tw$, where $x,t$ are fixed. Then, integrating over the image of $\varphi$ is the same as integrating over the ball of radius $t$ centered at $x$. Further, the Jacobian determinant is $t^2.$ Now, you just directly apply the change of variables formula.

To compute the Jacobian, we note that if we write $\varphi=(\varphi_1,\varphi_2), x=(x_1, x_2),$ and $w=(w_1, w_2),$ then $(\varphi_1(w),\varphi_2(w))=(x_1+tw_1, x_2+tw_2),$ and \begin{align*}\frac{\partial \varphi_1}{\partial w_1}&=t,\\
\frac{\partial \varphi_1}{\partial w_2}&=0,\\
\frac{\partial \varphi_2}{\partial w_1}&=t,\\
\frac{\partial \varphi_2}{\partial w_2}&=0,
\end{align*}
and we get the Jacobian $$D\varphi(w)=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial \varphi_1}{\partial w_1}& \frac{\partial \varphi_1}{\partial w_2}\\
\frac{\partial \varphi_2}{\partial w_1} & \frac{\partial \varphi_2}{\partial w_2} \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} t & 0 \\ 0 & t \end{pmatrix},$$ which has determinant $t^2.$

Comment: I feel like an idiot for not being able to figure this out, but can you explain how to compute the Jacobian determinant? I tried: Suppose $x = (x_1, x_2)$ is the center of the ball with radius $t$. Then $\varphi_1(w_1) = x_1 + t(r\cos\theta)$ and $\varphi_2(w_2) = x_2 + t(r\cos\theta)$. But when I calculate the partial derivatives of $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ with respect to $r$ and $\theta$ and calculate the Jacobian determinant, I don't get $t^2$.

Comment: Updated. You're overthinking it!

Comment: If you're especially insistent on doing it in polar coordinates, then you'll also get a factor of $r$. This is contained in the area form in your post, since they're writing $dw$.

Comment: Thank you so much!